# How to hide a div in Backbone when user clicks outside of div?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a View in Backbone that contains an inner div. I want to hide the div when the user clicks outside of the div.

I'm not sure how to set up an Event inside of the View that says "click NOT #inner_div": "removeDiv".

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual approach is to attach a click handler directly to `<body>` and then have that close or hide your `<div>`. For example:

```
render: function() {
    $('body').on('click', this.remove);
    this.$el.html('<div id="d"></div>');
    return this;
},
remove: function() {
    $('body').off('click', this.remove);
    // This is what the default `remove` does.
    this.$el.remove();
    return this;
}
```

If you just want to hide the `<div>` rather than remove it, just bind clicks on `<body>` to a different method than [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove); you'll still want to remove the click handler from `<body>` in your `remove` though. Also, you'll want to trap click events on your view's `el` to keep them from getting to `<body>`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/R698h/

If you have other elements that care about click events then you could absolutely position a `<div>` to cover up the `<body>` and then bind your click handler to that. You could have a look at the [jQuery BlockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) plugin to see how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Prototype, you can do this:

```
initialize: function() {
  // some code
  document.on('click', function(e, target) {
    if (target !== this.el && target.up('#inner_div').length === 0) {
      this.remove();
    }
  }.bind(this));
}
```

I guess with jQuery it might look like this:

```
initialize: function() {
  // some code
  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target !== this.el && e.target.parent('#inner_div').length === 0) {
      this.remove();
    }
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although manipulating the DOM directly works you could let Backbone handle things for you by giving your views some appropriate structure. For instance:

```
BoxView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click': '_click'
  },

  _click: function() {
    return false;
  }
});

AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.app',

  initialize: function() {
    this.boxView = new BoxView({ el: $('.box') })
  },

  events: {
    'click': '_click'
  },

  _click: function() {
    this.boxView.remove();
  }
});

new AppView({ el: $('.app') });
```

This way we can change the inner view once clicks on outer view are triggered. Note the binding on BoxView `click` event to prevent it from being disposed when user clicks on it.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/embs/45da2ppm/

In case you already have a complex structure of Backbone views that cannot be easily refactored into subviews structure, you may still make use of [Backbone.Events module](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) to listen to outer views' click events within the inner view and then manipulate it as you wish.

I'd also recommend checking out this nice [article](https://www.toptal.com/backbone-js/top-8-common-backbone-js-developer-mistakes) regarding common mistakes when working with Backbone. Some of them are closely related to your question:

- [Modifying DOM in Direct Response to Arbitrary Events](https://www.toptal.com/backbone-js/top-8-common-backbone-js-developer-mistakes#mistake-2-modifying-dom-in-direct-response-to-arbitrary-events)
- [Using jQuery “.on()” Instead of Delegated Events](https://www.toptal.com/backbone-js/top-8-common-backbone-js-developer-mistakes#mistake-8-using-jquery-on-instead-of-delegated-events)